# Partitioning File System Drive

Tags: installation, partitioning, filesystem

When installing Ubuntu I was told to set the size constraints for my File System drive and my... Other Stuff Drive (the official name). However, I slid the slider the wrong way, leaving me with 230gb of File System space (about 200 more than I'd need/want) and 16gb for absolutely everything else.

Is there any way to change these size constraints or repartition?

Thanks,

Harry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just download [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) Live CD Bootable Image , burn it to a CD, and boot from it.  Once booted make sure you un-mount the drive that you want to re-size.  Make sure that the partitions are next to each other, and disable swap if needed (if its between the partitions that you're trying to re-size).

[image]

**Note: When dealing with partitions always make sure that you have a full backup, just in case anything does wrong.**

Answer (score 0):

Go through [this detailed post](http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/) on how to resize ubuntu partitions.

For this solution, you will be using a *live CD* or a *live USB*, in order that the partitions are unused while being resized.

From live CD/USB, you will be running *Gparted* to resize the partitions.

Note: It is essential to *backup* all your important data before resizing.